# Tkinter OptionMenu error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, optionmenu

I'm having some issues getting my OptionMenu to work the first issue is that it wont work on it's on i have to use some placeholder label to get it to work. so in the below example it works if i use TaxYear as the master but not if i use TaxYearLi.

<strike>The second issue is that for some reason w.set("2018/2019") is not working i get an error that I'm passing a string not a stringvar</strike>

**Edit:** OK I've fixed the StringVar issue and setting a default value need to deffine root as Tk.Tk() if someone also could explain why this needs to be done that would be helpful.

```
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
w = Tk.StringVar
w.set("2018/2019")

TaxYear = Tk.Label(text="Select tax year")
TaxYear.grid(row=1, column=0)

TaxYearLi = Tk.OptionMenu(TaxYearLi, w, "2018/2019")
TaxYearLi.grid(row=1,column=1)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first parameter of `OptionMenu()` (as with all Tkinter widgets) is the parent widget - probably `root` in your case.  You cannot possibly pass the *widget itself* for this parameter, not only because that variable doesn't even exist yet!  (You also need to pass the parent widget in your call to `Label()`, you are getting a default rather than having any control over the process.)

Comment: @jasonharper, thanks for your help when you say i'm getting the default rather than having any control over the process what do you mean by this, can you give me an example of what control i would be missing. sorry but I'm very new to Tkinker and fairly new to python

Comment: If you do not specify a parent widget, Tkinter defaults to using a root window (from the first call to `Tk()`, I think).  Any reasonably complicated Tkinter window layout is likely to have many widgets that are children of Frames (or other containers) instead of the root, and therefore could not be created unless you actually specify the parent.

Comment: @jasonharper ah so is it best to make a frame to be the parent of a bunch of widget that are related?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to declare a variable (root in your case) as TK() is because Tk() is a class in Tkinter code which basicly create the window by asking it to your OS.
so you need to create a variable (some call it root others master, others parents) who's gona be your root/master/parent window and evry widget need to be on this variable.

Now about your OptionMenu, as i mentioned you need to put all your widgets on the main window (root in your case)

```
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
w = Tk.StringVar #in Python3 i need to put StringVar() i don't know about 2.x
w.set("2018/2019")

TaxYear = Tk.Label(text="Select tax year")
TaxYear.grid(row=1, column=0)
TaxYearLi = Tk.OptionMenu(root, w, "2018/2019") #needs to be on the root window
TaxYearLi.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```